# How to associate a Git branch with a local copy of master?

Tags: git, github, branch

I'm a complete git newbie, and I'm using the command line git ver 1.8.

```
$ git --version
git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)
```

I git cloned a local copy of a repo from Github.   Here's the status after cloning:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I have another local git repo that I want to integrate with the local copy.
Here's the status

```
$ git status
On branch loginbranch
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

How do I make the local copy of the "branch master" (that I cloned from the github repo) be the parent of the local loginbranch?

I want to do this so I can try to merge locally and safely before approaching the remote repo.

Total git newby, so when you use terms like master or origin, please say if they are keywords or pathnames. Maybe put pathnames in caps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is switch to your master branch,

`git checkout master`

then merge your updated branch.

`git merge loginbranch`

This will fast-forward your `master` branch to match `loginbranch`.  If you want to update the remote repo, you can then do

`git push origin master`

Afterwards, you can delete `loginbranch` via

`git branch -d loginbranch`

Comment: Did I mention I'm a total git newbie?   When I type "git branch master"  (I'm in the directory of my loginbranch), I get:    $ git branch master
fatal: A branch named 'master' already exists.        If I cd to the master branch and pick up with the second command, I get this:    $ git merge loginbranch
merge: loginbranch - not something we can merge.       At present there is no git association between loginbranch and master, and I want to create that, so I can merge.

Comment: Apologies, you want to do `git checkout master`.  This will switch to your master branch.  I accidentally wrote `git branch master` which will attempt to create a branch named `master`, which is why you received that error.

Comment: This just is not working for me.   IF I'm in a random directory, "git checkout master" comes back with an error message  "fatal: Not a git repository".     If I am in the dir with the master, it says "Already on master."     If I'm in the dir with the master and type the second command, "git merge loginbranch", I get "merge: loginbranch - not something we can merge".

Comment: Ok so it appears that you have 2 directories.  One which was created when you cloned from your remote repo.  How did you create the other one? When using git, you want to keep all files of a project in the same repo/directory.

Comment: Yes, I have two dirs, one was created by downloading and expanding a zip file from a git repo, then adding my changes, then git init; git add .   That dir is "loginbranch".   The other dir - created by clone from github. That's the local master.     Local master has many additional changes that were made into github.   loginbranch came from an earlier version of that repo.    I want login to merge into local master.  Then I hope to put localmaster (with loginbranch changes) into the remote repo.    I think I need a way to tell login branch "you are a child of this git folder over here (master)

Comment: Ok so I think this is what you have to do: Go to the directory that holds your `master` branch, and do `git checkout -b loginbranch`.  Then, copy the source files from the `loginbranch` directory into the `master` directory.  After this, you can stage + commit the changes into `loginbranch` which is in your `master` directory.  From there, you can follow the instructions above to merge the changes into your `master` branch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57066/discussion-between-user2066880-and-peter-vdl).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "do it within git" answer is to make the "loginbranch" directory a remote of the github clone directory, and then to create a new branch in the latter (from master) into which the "loginbranch" changes can be merged.  "git remote add" is how you make a link from one repository to another so that you can fetch and then merge changes from the "remote" repository (it doesn't have to literally be remote on another server -- it can be just a pathname to another directory).